# Delete duplicates in list. Why my codes go wrong ?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to write my codes to delete duplicates in a list. Here is first one:

```
a = [2,2,1,1,1,2,3,6,6]
b = [2,2,1,1,1,2,3,6,6]
for x in a:
  a.remove(x)
  if x in a:
     b.remove(x)
print('the list without duplicates is: ', b)
```

Unfortunately, it produces this result:

```
the list without duplicates is: [2, 1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Then I try to write the second one:

```
a = [2,2,1,1,1,2,3,6,6]
b = [2,2,1,1,1,2,3,6,6]
for i in range(len(a)): 
  for x in a:
    a.remove(x)
    if x in a:
        b.remove(x)    
print('the list without duplicates is: ', b)
```

And this second one produces the result as I expected:

```
the list without duplicates is:  [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

I really dont see why the second one is different from the first one. In fact, if I apply for the list:

```
[2,2,1,1,2,3,6,6]
```

Both of them produces the same result:

```
the list without duplicates is:  [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `set`

Comment: yeah, I want to try on my own before rely on the built-in.  I think it's good for newbie.

Comment: Just *Google* "python delete element while iterating".

Comment: Yea you could just google it, but generally, removing elements from a list while you are iterating over it is bad practice. Though sometimes I do this anyway... But your question is just why the second one worked?

Comment: yeah, for me both of them are just the same right ? I cannot see any difference. In fact, when I execute my first one by pen and paper I do exactly like the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`why the second one is different`

The for loop keeps track of the index it is *on*. When you remove an item from the list, it messes up the count: the item that was at index `i+1` has now become the item at index `i` and gets *skipped* in the next iteration.

To illustrate:

```
a_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
for i, item in enumerate(a_list):
    print(f"i:{i}, item:{item}, a_list[i+1]:{a_list[i+1]}")
    print(f"\tremoving {item}", end = ' ---> ')
    a_list.remove(item)
    print(f"a_list[i+1]:{a_list[i+1]}")
>>>
i:0, item:a, a_list[i+1]:b
    removing a ---> a_list[i+1]:c
i:1, item:c, a_list[i+1]:d
    removing c ---> a_list[i+1]:e
i:2, item:e, a_list[i+1]:f
    removing e ---> a_list[i+1]:g
i:3, item:g, a_list[i+1]:h
....
```

---

Your second solution works because even though you are *skipping* items in the for loop, you have added an outer loop that revisits the process and operates on those *skipped* items.  In the last iteration, because you are *skipping* items, there is always one of the *duplicate* values left.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use the built-in set, it is way easier to create a new list and add new elements to it if they aren't duplicate.

Something like:

```
a = [2,2,1,1,1,2,3,6,6]
c = []
for item in a:
    if item not in c:
        c.append(item)
```